# URGENT: Can you please help decide the correct verb to be?

Tags: verbs, be

Please leave the construction the same way - unless there is something seriously wrong with it - and please help decide the verb:

There **IS** much information to be reviewed and processed, and more information to be obtained, then many meetings to be made.

vs.

There **ARE** much information to be reviewed and processed, and more information to be obtained, then many meetings to be made.

The confusion is not because of the uncountable noun 'information' but rather because the construction of the sentence should suggest:

- There IS/ARE 1) much information to be reviewed and processed and 2) more information to be obtained then 3) many meetings to be made.

But since the flow of the sentence seems interrupted, I think 'is' the right verb to be, but not sure if this would be ok because the rest will be without a verb then. Again, the key is to keep the construction the same because it relays a specific message.

Thank you very much!

Comment: If it's urgent, you've come to the wrong place. That's not how we work here.

Comment: Sorry, desperately need urgent help. Thank you though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit conflicted over the form the sentence takes as a whole, and would strongly suggest reformulating it:

> There is much information to be reviewed and processed, and more information to be obtained; there are then many meetings to be made.

By doing so you avoid needing to use a single copula for every aspect of the sentence, and although largely subjective, I'd suggest it reads better as well.

Comment: Thank you very much. But it seems not possible to keep the exact same formatting of the sentence, right?

Comment: Losing the passive voice would go a long way toward making the sentence more palatable. As originally written, it's irretrievably awkward and ugly.